# How do i get the API Key AND Secret for a Facebook Page not the App page?

Tags: facebook, api, key

How do i get the API Key AND Secret for a Facebook Page not the App page?
I need to use when using the "stream_publish" function.
Please help

Answer (score 1):

To post as the Page, you need to get an access token for the page by getting an access token for an admin of the Page with the "manage_pages" and "publish_stream" permissions.

Then, using that access token, hit

https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=THE_ACCESS_TOKEN.

You'll get a JSON output of all the Pages that user admins and in there you'll see an access token for each Page. If you use one of those access tokens to POST your message, you will be doing so as the Page.

The process is outlined in the documentation [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#page-login)

Answer (score 0):

stream_publish is only for application. It's not for pages